# Class compare vs instanceof in equals method java

Tags: java, spring, object, entity, equals

Like in a title: 
My Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Example {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // fields, getters & setters ommited 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Example example = (Example) o;

        return id != null ? id.equals(examle.id) : examle.id == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Auto generated equals method looks like above.

My questions are:

1. Why do I need to manually replace:

> o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()

into

> !(o instanceof
>   Example)

2. What will happen if the objects of this class will be placed in java.util.Set? In what part the rule of contract will be violated?

Comment: 1. **Why** indeed?

Comment: You don't need to replace it.

Comment: its not the same in case of entity it seems.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that instanceof  will return true if o has inheritance of the object whereas getClass comparation will check if both objects are strictly the same class.

Comment: Ok, now I see the difference. But can you answer for my second question?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, in your own classes it is almost always better to use

```
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
```

This is in particular the case when you plan to create subclasses of your class and override `equals`, but also when you're not planning that this will work without problem (in most cases). So you don't need to manually replace anything.

The reason is the following. The `equals` method is required to induce an equivalence relation on objects, in particular it is supposed to be symmetric: if `a.equals(b)` it must also be the case that `b.equals(a)` and vice versa. Many classes which use the `equals` method, such as maps and sets, assume this behavior.

Now, suppose you replace `o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()` with `!(o instanceof Example)`, and create a subclass a follows:

```
class Subclass extends Example {
    String address;
    // fields, getters and setters
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!o instanceof Subclass) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.equals(o) && Objects.equals(((Subclass)o).address, address);
        }
    }
}
```

Now consider the following code:

```
Example a = new Example(); 
a.setId(1);
a.setName("A");
Subclass b = new Subclass();
b.setId(1);
b.setName("A");
b.setAddress("Street 1");
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // Prints true
System.out.println(b.equals(a)); // Prints false
```

You have now an `equals` method which is not symmetric, and this may lead to problems when using collections.

Note, however, that in *some* cases, you actually want to use `instanceof`. For example, the Javadoc for the `equals` method of the interface `Set` specifies that two sets are considered equal when they contain the same elements. So, a `HashSet` is equal to a `TreeSet` if they contain the same elements, even though the two sets belong to different classes. In such cases, of course, it is not appropriate to use `getClass() == o.getClass()`